# Создание uefi флешки с дальнейшей загрузкой уже установленной ОС

Tags: windows, bios, uefi

Всех приветствую. Просят установить на флешку загрузчик uefi, чтобы через gpt разметку сетевая карта Соболя загружалась и стартовала уже установленная Винда. (напрямую сетевая карта соболя не загружается на установленной винде на жестком диске, только если флешку с установщиком воткнуть) Жесткий диск с виндой трогать нельзя. Пока нахожу только информацию о том, что через easyuefi или WinSetupfromUsb можно либо изменить порядок загрузки устройств на компе (что с таким же успехом можно сделать и через биос), либо сделать загрузочную флешку с уефи (через WinSetupfromUsb) с двумя iso образами систем. Только смысла от последнего я не вижу, тк грузиться будет в любом случае образ с флешки, а не жесткий диск с уже установленной Виндой. Возможно ли вообще сделать так, чтобы сетевая карта, которая требует gpt загрузчика загрузилась через uyfi с разметкой gpt и подцепилась к жесткому диску с установленной виндой? То есть суть такая: Сетевая карта соболя грузится через gpt (не mbr) -> uefi с gpt -> Установленная винда на жестком диске

Comment: Что за Соболь ?

Comment: @donRumata Видимо, система защиты. У нас такая для передачи данных карточек пациентов. Стартует до загрузки ОС. Заменяет ли загрузку UEFI на собственную или нет - не знаю, не разбирался.

Comment: @donRumata средство защиты информации. в виде сетевой карты. ставится в pci-express и выбирается первым в приоритете загрузки биос. Второй в приоритете поставил виндовс 7, но в таком случае по dhcp айпишник сетевая соболя не получает, в случае, если вторым в приоритете стоит загрузочная флешка с виндовс10, то соболь запускается, но за ним, естественно, следует установка винды 10. На киберфоруме посоветовали воткнуть изернет кабель напрямую в карту соболя, буду пробовать

Comment: Ааа, быдложелезки для типа надёжной передачи. Ну могу только посочувстсовать и посоветовать написать официальной поддержке. Мы на 2 компах юзаем vipnet и там всё тоже очень плохо.